# Resolving Runtime 424 Error; ActiveChart.SetSourceData

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

Good afternoon,

Beginner working with a legacy macro written in 2002. Macro simply compiles data from different workbooks and creates a new file with a chart. Upgrading PC from Excel 2003 to present has caused a handful of bugs that mostly have been resolved. One of the last remaining problems is the sub that builds the charts. The initial error (1004) occurred at the line

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(_
PlotCells), PlotBy:=XlColumns
```

After some research I found info here...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce290e29-634b-4383-9bb5-fddda8db3974/excel-macro-not-able-to-setsourcedata-for-chart?forum=isvvba
that led me to change that line to

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=PlotCells, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

The 1004 error no longer occurs but now its been replaced by a 424 error. Unsure what is the cause as I believe I dimensioned everything properly and passed data from one sub to the next. PlotCells contains a value when debugging. Full Sub posted below.

```
Sub Build_Chart(ByVal File_Path As String, ByVal NumFreq As String, ByVal NumTemp As String, ByRef FreqV() As String)
    '
    ' Macro6 Macro
    ' Macro recorded 1/11/02 by Edward P. Smith
    '
    ' Making the Plot

        
    Dim X_Column, FCell, PlotCells, ii, tt, Freq, Cell, W_Book
    
    
    X_Column = "J"
    FCell = NumFreq + 3
    PlotCells = X_Column & FCell & ","
        
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=File_Path
    W_Book = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
    'Add the Chart
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        
    For ii = 1 To NumFreq
        'Get the values to Plot
    
        For tt = 1 To NumTemp - 2
            If Not tt = NumTemp - 2 Then
                PlotCells = PlotCells & X_Column & (FCell + tt * (NumFreq + 1)) & ","
            Else
                PlotCells = PlotCells & X_Column & (FCell + tt * (NumFreq + 1))
            End If
        Next tt
        If ii = 1 Then
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=PlotCells, PlotBy:=xlColumns
                ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
        Else
            Sheets("Data").Select
            Range(PlotCells).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Chart1").Select
            ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Paste Rowcol:=xlColumns, SeriesLabels:=False, _
                CategoryLabels:=False, Replace:=False, NewSeries:=True
        End If
        
        FCell = FCell + 1
        PlotCells = X_Column & FCell & ","
    Next ii
        
    ' Title the Chart and Axis
    
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "PPM Change"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "PPM"
    End With
    
    ' Name the plot series
    
    For ii = 1 To NumFreq
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ii).Name = "=""" & MyRound(FreqV(ii - 1), 2) & " GHz"""
    Next ii
      
    ' Set the X-Axis values to the temperatures
    For ii = 1 To NumFreq
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ii).XValues = _
            "=Data!R" & ((NumFreq + 1) * NumTemp) + 4 & "C1:R" & (((NumFreq + 1) * NumTemp) + 3) + (NumTemp - 1) & "C1"
    Next ii
        
    ' Set the Scale to our default values
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = -1000
        .MaximumScale = 2000
        .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Crosses = xlCustom
        .CrossesAt = -1000
        .ReversePlotOrder = False
        .ScaleType = xlLinear
    End With
    
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
        .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Crosses = xlCustom
        .CrossesAt = -1000
        .ReversePlotOrder = False
        .ScaleType = xlLinear
    End With

    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    
    With Selection.Border
        .ColorIndex = 16
        .Weight = xlThin
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    Windows(W_Book).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    'MyDelay 20
    
    ActiveWindow.Close


End Sub
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `PlotCells` looks like a `String`, not a `Range`. You should `Debug.Print` it to see what it is. Btw, that code could use a rewrite, it's got some bad practices. Maybe start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I do not doubt that! Just trying to get by without a full rewrite currently. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1):

The initial 1004 "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" Error was probably caused by the length of `PlotCells` exceeding the maximum number of characters(255) that a Range will accept.

The 424 "Object required" Error is being thrown because `Source` is expecting a Range object not a string.

If `Len(`PlotCells`)` > 255 then you will have to use `Union()` to build your range.